# Aiogram не получается отправить видео через inline

Tags: python, aiogram-3.x

Использовал @ inline_query

```
    print(text)  
    input_content = InputTextMessageContent(message_text=text) #формируем контент ответного сообщения\  
    print(input_content)  
    result_id = hashlib.md5(text.encode()).hexdigest() #сделали уникальный id   
    from tBOT import bot  
    item = InlineQueryResultCachedVideo( 
        id=result_id, 
        title="Это тестовый запрос", 
        description="desc", 
        video_file_id="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4", 
        mime_type="video/mp4", 
        thumbnail_url="https://samplelib.com/lib/preview/mp4/sample-15s.jpg", 
        caption="<b>Это тестовый запрос</b>", 
        reply_markup=kb.menu 
        ) 
    await bot.answer_inline_query( 
        inline_query_id=inline_query.id, 
        results=[item], 
        cache_time=1 
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Надо было использовать **file_id**, который подставляется вместо ссылки, узнать его только можно отправив видео собственному боту, (код есть в интернете) с собственным хендлером. На другие видео не получится узнать его.

> Нужно чтобы видео загрузилось на официальные сервера телеграм, об этом говориться в документации.

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).